# Crop/Trim marks in XeLaTeX as like as dvips option

Tags: xetex, croptrim

New Year wishes to all...

By using `dvips.exe`, if we give `-k*` option, then the crop marks comes by auto, is there any same method available in `XeLaTeX` to get the cropmarks by auto? I am using `MikTeX v2.9` for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`crop`](https://ctan.org/pkg/crop) package to do this.

You could use it in your original document.

Or you could make a new document and include the PDF produced by your `xelatex` run. This is a little more similar to the `dvips -k` option.

e.g., if you have an existing PDF on `letterpaper` called `fromxetex.pdf`, you can add crop marks to it like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[width=9.5in,height=12in,center,cross]{crop}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{fromxetex.pdf}
\end{document}
```

See the documentation for the `crop` package on ho to customise everything.